# Tableau Desktop - Trying to get Rolling 12 months,The rolling 12 months should pull even at the starting point

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I am trying to get rolling 12 months calculation in Tableau which is working fine but it's not applying at the starting date.
Eg i want rolling 12 months from jan 2012 to till date. But even jan 2012 should display rolling 12 previous months.(eg it should show total value of last 12 months from jan 2012 to feb 2011.

How can i do that in tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Use a late filter for the date. LOOKUP(ATTR([Date]),0)

Use that to remove the dates before 2012 but keeping the running sum from before then.

A late filter happens after the numbers have calculated, hence starting your running sum while accounting for what happened in the past.

[This link](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-filter-display-data-only/) has an example specifically referencing the running sum starting point.

Comment: Thanks,but te date is a parameter,so what ever date they  select they should get rolling 2 months for that start date parameter.